# How can I prevent the VS Code Prettier extension from addint "/** @format */" at the top of my file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Whenever I save my file especially JavaScript or typescript files in VS Code it formats it using prettier and at the top of file it adds `/** @format */`. I don't want this but I want formatting to work. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
"prettier.insertPragma": false,
```

in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

And make it format on save:

[image]

More [reference](https://scottsauber.com/2017/06/10/prettier-format-on-save-never-worry-about-formatting-javascript-again/)